# Drawing Hexagons shapes using CSS only

Tags: css, shapes, hexagonal-tiles

I have found examples of how to draw triangles and circles using just CSS3 (with no Javascript), but I did not find any sample of how to draw hexagons. Is it possible? Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try anything yet, did you search Google? If so, why didn't you show us what you did? Are you asking us to drop everything and do your research for you? Good job. *sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Liew wrote an excellent article about drawing hexagons just with CSS3:

http://www.queness.com/post/13901/create-beautiful-hexagon-shapes-with-pure-css3

If you want a COMPASS SCSS version of that code, including scaling feature, see my code at:

http://codepen.io/interdruper/details/GrBEk

Hope it helps